# Subject Verb Agreement when everyone in a group owns a collective noun?

Tags: nouns, verb-agreement, uncountable-nouns

If there is an uncountable noun, then a singular verb is used.

> The equipment was stolen.

What if everybody in a team has some equipment and some of the equipment was stolen?

> 1a. The equipment of each team member was stolen.

sounds more right than

> 1. The equipment of each team member were stolen.

What if only five team members had their equipment stolen?

> 2a. The equipment of five team members was stolen.

or

> 2b. The equipment of five team members were stolen.

Also, does it change if it becomes a countable noun instead of an uncountable noun?

> 3a. The towels of five team members was stolen.

as opposed to

> 3b. The towels of five team member were stolen.

Comment: The number of owners makes no difference. Equipment was stolen, towels were stolen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually the head noun in the subject noun phrase that determines the agreement of the verb. In both of the examples below, the head noun is the uncountable noun *equipment*:

- The equipment was stolen.
- The equipment of each team member was stolen.
- The equipment of five team members was stolen.

Because *equipment* is uncountable, the sentences will be ungrammatical with plural agreement:

- *The equipment were stolen. (ungrammatical)
- *The equipment of each team member were stolen. (ungrammatical)
- *The equipment of five team members were stolen. (ungrammatical)

If we use a plural noun as the head, then we will see compulsory plural agreement:

- The towels of five team members were stolen.
- *The towels of five team members was stolen. (ungrammatical)
- Five team members' towels were stolen.
- *Five team members' towels was stolen. (ungrammatical)

Comment: Why is it "five team member's" rather than "five team members'"?

Comment: @j1119  Sorry, that was a typo:)